# Not able to Line Spacing value between 0 to 1 in TextFragment Aspose.pdf

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

I'm trying to set the line spacing of a TextFragment object using Aspose.pdf in C#, but I'm unable to set the value between 0 to 1.

I also want to set the line spacing to a value less than 1, such as 0.82, but it seems to be getting rounded up to 1. I've verified that the font file exists at the specified path,

```
var fontPath = _dataDir + "astmensh.otf";
var document = new Aspose.Pdf.Document();
var page = document.Pages.Add();

TextBuilder builder = new TextBuilder(page);
TextParagraph paragraph = new TextParagraph();

paragraph.Rectangle = new BoundingBox(pageHeight).getBoxPosition(70.136f, 148.652f, 425.665f, 549.093f);
paragraph.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
paragraph.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
paragraph.FormattingOptions.WrapMode = TextFormattingOptions.WordWrapMode.ByWords;
paragraph.FormattingOptions.LineSpacing = TextFormattingOptions.LineSpacingMode.FontSize;

var textFragment = new Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragment(@"Greetings Ms. test999,
    I wanted to let you know I am thinking of you.");

textFragment.TextState.Font = FontRepository.OpenFont(fontPath);
textFragment.TextState.ForegroundColor = Color.Parse("#211d70");
textFragment.TextState.FontSize = 28;
textFragment.TextState.LineSpacing = 0.82f;

paragraph.AppendLine(textFragment);
builder.AppendParagraph(paragraph);
document.Save(_dataDir + "manual-output.pdf");
```

Comment: The issue seems related to the specific font. Would you please create a post on official Aspose.PDF support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf/10) along with sharing the font file with you post? As this is the right place to discuss such issues. We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: no, it's not related to a specific font (Download any font from google font and check). As Adobe Acrobat also does not allow setting line-height / line-spacing between 0 to 1. But In my case, I need to set it between 0 to 1.

I have already created a thread on forum - https://forum.aspose.com/t/not-able-to-add-line-spacing-value-in-decimal-between-0-0-to-1-0-in-textfragment-aspose-pdf/262487

Comment: We have seen your post and have responded there as well. You may please follow up there for further updates.